# Can I use ms-Spinner in my office-js Excel web add-in without a framework such as 'react'?

Tags: office-js, excel-addins, office-fabric

I've built an Excel add-in (Using Office-js, TypeScript, HTML, JQuery, CSS, Visual Studio 2019) which manipulates an Excel spreadsheet, and I'd like to display progress messages with a progress spinner. I think the ms-Spinner in UI Fabric would fit the bill. Can I use it with HTML/JQuery/CSS or do I need a framework like react?

I've tried this in javascript, but it throws an exception:

```
        var spin = document.querySelector('.ms-Spinner');
        if (spin) spinnerComponent = new components.Spinner(spin);
        // Unhide and start the spinner
        $(".ms-Spinner").show();
        if (spinnerComponent) spinnerComponent.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to the spinner from [Fabric React](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/), then you have to use React. However, there is a non-React set of Fabric controls at [Fabric.js](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric-js) including a spinner which you can use. That said, we used it in this sample and it seldom actually renders: [PowerPoint Add-in Microsfot Graph ASP.NET InsertChart](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChart).

Comment: Adding:     <script src="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js"></script> to my html and changing my code to:  spinnerComponent = new fabric.Spinner(spin); did the trick. The spinner control can be instantiatied/started/stopped now from js. However, https://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/avoid-the-office-ui-fabric-javascript-package/ makes a good point about not using fabric-js.

Comment: Andrew is correct that Office UI Fabric JS components are deemphasized. However, React isn't always the right choice for an Office add-in. For devs, like yourself, who don't use React, but would like to maintain compatibility with the Fabric look 'n' feel; we continue to support the Fabric Core CSS and we also have the no-longer-maintained set of framework-independent controls that I linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any frond-end library or framework for office-add-ins.you do not need to depend on react-js to develop office add-in